# Adding currency unit in Prawn PDF? (syntax error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, currency, prawn

I'm working on a PDF invoice using Prawn PDF. I am trying to use `number_to_currency` whilst passing the `unit`.

```
def line_item_rows
 [["Description", "Qty", "Unit Price", "Price GBP"]] +
 @invoice.line_items.map do |item|
  [item.name, item.quantity, price(item.unit_price), price(item.full_price)]
 end
end

@view.number_to_currency(num, :unit => "£")
```

The above results in an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
@view.number_to_currency(num, :unit => "£")
                                          ^):
```

If I use the HTML value instead it simply outputs the raw html:

```
@view.number_to_currency(num, :unit => "&pound;")
Total &pound;2,266.00
```

Is there a particular way of adding a £ when using Prawn PDF? The above attempts work fine when using html/erb but not when using Prawn PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby probably isn't treating your source file as utf-8:

```
# encoding: US-ASCII <-- it's defaulting to this
puts "£"
```

So when it compiles:

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
foo.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
foo.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
foo.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
puts("£")
        ^
```

Add an encoding hint at the top of your file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
puts("£")
```

And it should run:

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
£
```